# How do I install Paystack Payment Plugin on My Magento 2.3 Site

Tags: magento2, extensions

I would like to install paystack payment plugin on my site, I have downloaded the zip file but the issue is that I don't see the familiar magento 2 directories after unzipping the package where I could just copy the files to the corresponding directories on my magento 2 root directory.
Please how do I install the plugin in a scenario like this?

[image: Screenshot of the unzipped package of the Plugin]

[image: Screenshot of my magento root directory]

Comment: Check my answer and try #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you use this repo](https://github.com/PaystackHQ/plugin-magento-2) then you can install two ways.

1. Using the composer that already described in the readme section.
2. Create a directory under **app/code** which is **Pstk/Paystack**. So the location looks like : **app/code/Pstk/Paystack**
   and unzip here your code.

Now your folder looks like :

> app/code/Pstk/Paystack/Block
>
> app/code/Pstk/Paystack/Api

etc.

Now run setup upgrade command for installation this module

Comment: After creating the directory app/code/Pstk/Paystack/ and unzipping the package there what next? should I still run this command?      composer require pstk/paystack-magento2-module

Comment: No need to run composer. you need to run setup:upgrade command for installation.

Comment: After creating the directory app/code/Pstk/Paystack/ and unzipping the package there
I ran the command: php bin/magento setup:upgrade                                                                  it returned the error: Could not open input file: bin/magento

Comment: I have gotten it to work, the command ran succesfully, so what next should I run this command? php bin/magento setup:di:compile